# Cannot link linker.ld

Tags: c, gcc, linker, operating-system, windows-10

I am currently following the Bare Bones tutorial from OSDev and i have set up everything and compiled the kernel and bootloader into object files, and i have the .ld file. However, when i try to link the files and produce it into a bin using `i686-elf-gcc -T linker.ld -o myos.bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib boot.o kernel.o -lgcc`, i get this error:

```
.../i686/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-elf/4.8.2/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld.exe: cannot open linker script file linker.ld

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using GCC and using the compiled version of i686-elf-gcc which includes many more compilers and i have added 4 dlls as it was missing (also not related to linker), but i installed MinGW and added them. I am on Windows 10 x64. Many of the solutions or workarounds i find just brings up more errors or does absolutely nothing to the errors (-T doesn't do anything, -noixemul is not a parameter.). I removed multiboot content since i am gonna use a sector-long bootloader which loads the object files.

Comment: Are you sure that was the full output of gcc?

Comment: see if the file is present ... try versbose option `-Wl,--verbose` for additional information like where is the linker searching for the linker script ... if there is the file see what permissions are `ls -al` might help

Answer (score 2):

If i'm not mistaken, your problem is really, *really*, ***really*** simple:

You don't have access to `linker.ld`. Try running as superuser or changing the permissions.

If this doesn't solve it, you have an actual problem. Try not using the `-T` flag.

Comment: This is a bad and possibly dangerous solution. The better advice would be to simply `chmod` or `chown` `linker.ld` so the current user _does_ have permission to read that file. **There is no reason to run the linker as root other than these file permissions!**

Comment: Ah, pretty sure OP said he was on Windows 10.  Last I checked, no root there.